# How to apply a class to only clicked/selected div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I currently have a toggling function to show different content that is working perfectly using jQuery. Below is my code!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tab-nav-wrapper div .toggle-item').click(function() {
    $('.tab-content-wrapper > div').hide();
    $('.tab-content-wrapper > div').eq($(this).parent().index()).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.item-active {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.tab2-c,
.tab3-c,
.tab4-c {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-nav-wrapper">
  <div class="one">
    <div class="toggle-item">
      <h3>Item One</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <div class="toggle-item">
      <h3>Item Two</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    <div class="toggle-item">
      <h3>Item Three</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="four">
    <div class="toggle-item">
      <h3>Item Four</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tab-content-wrapper">
  <div class="tab1-c">
    <p>This is ONE</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab2-c">
    <p>This is TWO</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab3-c">
    <p>This is THREE</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab4-c">
    <p>This is FOUR</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**I want to apply the CSS class 'item-active' to only the active/selected 'toggle-item'. I know I am really close... I just don't know much/enough of JS/jQuery to quite get the answer. Thank you in advance!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- To select selected/clicked element use `$(this)`

2- To add/remove class use `.addClass();` and `.removeClass()`

3- To remove the class from unselected divs use `siblings()` but while `toggle-item` elements not siblings then you can use `.parent().siblings().find('.toggle-item')` then `.removeClass()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tab-nav-wrapper div .toggle-item').click(function(){  
        $(this).addClass('item-active').parent().siblings().find('.toggle-item').removeClass('item-active');
        $('.tab-content-wrapper > div').hide().eq($(this).parent().index()).show();
    });
});
```

```css
.item-active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.tab2-c, .tab3-c, .tab4-c {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-nav-wrapper">
  <div class="one">
    <div class="toggle-item">
      <h3>Item One</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <div class="toggle-item">
      <h3>Item Two</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    <div class="toggle-item">
      <h3>Item Three</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="four">
    <div class="toggle-item">
      <h3>Item Four</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tab-content-wrapper">
  <div class="tab1-c"><p>This is ONE</p></div> 
  <div class="tab2-c"><p>This is TWO</p></div> 
  <div class="tab3-c"><p>This is THREE</p></div> 
  <div class="tab4-c"><p>This is FOUR</p></div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use jquery function addClass() so your code will be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tab-nav-wrapper div .toggle-item').click(function(){  
      $(this).addClass('item-active');
        $('.tab-content-wrapper > div').hide();
        $('.tab-content-wrapper > div').eq($(this).parent().index()).show();
    });
});
```

this will activate the class each time you click on an element, but if you want to select only focused element(and not another one) your code should be like that:

```
var lastSelected = null;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tab-nav-wrapper div .toggle-item').click(function(){ 
      if(lastSelected != null) lastSelected.removeClass('item-active');
        $(this).addClass('item-active');
        lastSelected =$(this);
        $('.tab-content-wrapper > div').hide();
        $('.tab-content-wrapper > div').eq($(this).parent().index()).show();
    });
});
```

this code will keep track of last selected element, and delet the item-active class from it, good luck.

Comment: Well the main problem here is selecting only one element on each click(or better say applying item-active class on one element only on each click)  so using toggleClass() or addClass() would depend on his needs since they have the same effect (with advantage to toggleClass() that allows him to remove the class back)

Answer (score 0):

in pure JavaScript you can use className this way:

will change the class attribute value to newClass
`element.className='newClass';`

use many classes as well
`element.className='newClass anotherClass';`

or even retrieve all CSS classes writing a blank class name
`element.className='';`

will be nearly the same as
èlement.removeAttribute('class');
(nearly but not exactly the same) because setting .className to empty value keep the class(so easier to fill again) and using removeAttribute comptely delete the attribute from element(so you've to add it again in order to set one, that will neither be a problem because the method `.setAttribute('class', value)` will set attribute and add it if none exist).

In this case JQuery is not really quicker to write or easier and pure Javascript will be quicker to go anyway. Even if i like JQuery selector(who're quicker to write and easier to read as well) and the .removeClass method (mind in -Mohamed-Youssef to replace sibilings by siblings who is a type error but answer is right too).